# mysql unix_timestamp duplicate for datetime

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am getting the same unix timestamp for two diferent datetimes:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-03-09 02:00:00")
--> 1394352000

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-03-09 03:00:00")
--> 1394352000
```

Thanks in advances for any idea to fix this issue.

Additionally I have checked on an horary list from december 22, 2013 to Abril 2019 and I have found duplicates for this dates:

```
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1394352000, FECHA_HORA = 9/3/2014 2:00
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1394352000, FECHA_HORA = 9/3/2014 2:00

UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1425801600, FECHA_HORA = 8/3/2015 2:00
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1425801600, FECHA_HORA = 8/3/2015 3:00

UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1457856000, FECHA_HORA = 13/3/2016 2:00
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1457856000, FECHA_HORA = 13/3/2016 3:00

UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1489305600, FECHA_HORA = 12/3/2017 2:00
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1489305600, FECHA_HORA = 12/3/2017 3:00

UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1520755200, FECHA_HORA = 11/3/2018 2:00
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1520755200, FECHA_HORA = 11/3/2018 3:00

UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1552204800, FECHA_HORA = 10/3/2019 2:00
UNIX TIMESTAMP = 1552204800, FECHA_HORA = 10/3/2019 3:00
```

For converting the before date time format to the format accepted by UNIX_TIMESTAMP I used:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( STR_TO_DATE("9/3/2014 2:00", '%e/%c/%Y %k:%i') );
```

Comment: I've tried in multiple ways but I cannot replicate your situation. What is the original datatype for `FECHA_HORA`?

Comment: I use d/m/YY. So, for converting this format to the format accepted by the function, I use the function STR_TO_DATE in this way: STR_TO_DATE("9/3/2014 2:00", '%e/%c/%Y %k:%i').

Comment: I think so is you enter this two lines in your SQL box inside PhpMySql y can reproduce the issue:

Comment: SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( STR_TO_DATE("9/3/2014 2:00", '%e/%c/%Y %k:%i') );

Comment: SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( STR_TO_DATE("9/3/2014 3:00", '%e/%c/%Y %k:%i') );